# Get coincident and not coincident rows in two tables under conditions

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
TABLE1

ID T3_ID PERIOD AGENT
1   1    2016   12
2   2    2016   13
3   3    2016   12
4   4    2015   12
```

and

```
TABLE2

ID T3_ID PERIOD PRODUCT 
1   1    2016   'PRODUCT1'
2   3    2016   'PRODUCT2'
3   3    2015   'PRODUCT2'
```

I need to get all rows from both tables that match certain conditions and joining by T3_ID field. But in the case that in Table2 there isn't a matching row in Table2 for any T3_ID record in Table1, showing it anyway.
The expected result in this example would be:

```
 EXPECTED RESULT

ID T3_ID PERIOD AGENT PRODUCT
1   1    2016   12    'PRODUCT1'
2   2    2016   13    ''
3   3    2016   12    'PRODUCT2'
```

I already built a query, it works and shows expected results, but I wonder if there's a better way of doing this.

```
SELECT T1.*, '' AS PRODUCT FROM TABLE1 T1
WHERE T1.PERIOD='2016' AND T1.T3_ID NOT IN (SELECT T2.T3_ID FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T2.PERIOD='2016')
UNION
SELECT T1.*, T2.PRODUCT AS PRODUCT FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.T3_ID=T2.T3_ID
```

Comment: You can use an OUTER JOIN it retrieves you the coincident and non coincident values of tables. I leave you a link explaining better the differences between OUTER JOIN and INNER JOIN:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join

Comment: Try it, and you'll see that it doesn't work with outer join

Comment: Somebody please!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you are using SQL Server

```
SELECT T1.*, ISNULL(T2.PRODUCT,'') AS PRODUCT FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.T3_ID=T2.T3_ID
WHERE T1.PERIOD='2016'
```

Comment: I have to include T2.period='2016' to restrict results to this year. Your solution still doesn't show all matched records from Table1

Comment: The problem is not that a row Product field is null in Table2, the problem is that for a specific T3_ID in Table1 there is no matching T3_ID in Table2, so the record is not retrieved. So checking for NULL doesn't work